# How to proxy VideoJS Source from ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, proxy, cross-domain

I'm trying to create a simple [www.myserver.com/proxy.php](http://www.myserver.com/proxy.php) in order to stream www.mediafire/myvideo.mp4 back to the browser. I do this to avoid CORS error when calling the video directly from the browser. (mediafire server doesn't allows CORS)

In the post below I found the code, but:

> How do I fetch the ajax response back to the  element in VideoJS?

Many Thanks

[AJAX cross domain call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558977/ajax-cross-domain-call)

**The jQuery part:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'proxy.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response) {
        // response now contains myfile.mp4
    }
});
```

**the PHP (proxy.php):**

```
echo file_get_contents("www.mediafire.com/myvid.mp4");
```

**And a simple VideoJS script:**

```
    <video
        id="fplayer"
        class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-16-9"
        controls
        preload="none"
      
        data-setup='{"fluid": false}'>
        <source src="??" type="application/x-mpegURL"> 
       // it was: <source src="www.mediafire.com/myvid.mp4">
    </video>
```

The link below suggest to build the HTML videoJS element once I get the ajax response.
But the datatype is JSON, whereas I'm fetching a binary **MP4** or a **m3u8** video and I'm not sure if putting the response in the Source element will work. In addition VideoJS may **not** initialize using this solution because the Video element doesn't exist when page load is ready.

[Load video source into videojs or mediaelementjs dynamically from ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27909568/load-video-source-into-videojs-or-mediaelementjs-dynamically-from-ajax)

Comment: Why are you involving Ajax at all?

Comment: How do I overcome CORS otherwise? I've no access to the remote server, so I suppose the only option is to create a proxy on my server which in turn will send back data to the browser - without breaking CORS rule.

Comment: "so I suppose the only option is to create a proxy on my server which in turn will send back data to the browser" — which you've done. Now make it use GET and put the URL in the `src` attribute.

Comment: I was trying to gain some bandwidth, but I found that most cloud storage providers don't allow their clients to edit HTTP headers (except AWS).

Answer (score -2):

We can use AJAX to make a request to our local server, and then use a proxy such as Express JS (Node JS) which is able to route the request to the local video we want to stream. But streaming a video from a remote server (eg. mediafire.com) requires full access to the HTTP Headers, which they're usually not willing to provide.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31053493)

Comment: OK, got it thanks. Probably a better answer is: we can use AJAX to make a request to our local server, and then use a proxy such as Express JS (Node JS) which is able to route the request to the local video we want to stream. But streaming a video from a remote server (eg. mediafire.com) requires full access to the HTTP Headers, which they're usually not willing to provide.